# D3.js shape gets translated in display after transition as if coordinate system had changed

Tags: d3.js

This animation tries to illustrate balls following a curved line "falling" into a bucket:

(1)  https://bl.ocks.org/max-l/ddfef6f8415675878baba32080d6a874/bae06bead60551cdae7488faccaa0d9c5624455c

For a reason that I can't understand, in (1), the balls get "teleported" outside the rectangle, it's as if the display suddenly had changed coordinate system.

The following code illustrates what should happen at the end of the transition: the balls should bounce in the rectangle that represents a bucket:

(2) https://bl.ocks.org/max-l/cda07bafcf7970e724b3aa00aefe9a02/8230c5db14e666efcb833c6c41c3c941f836729f

Why do the circles get "teleported" on the display, while the x,y coordinate shows no such "teleportation" ?

```
function redraw(data){
  var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)

  circle.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", radius)  
  .transition()
  .ease(d3.easeQuad) 
  .delay(rndDelay)
  .duration(2000)
  .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
  .on("end", d => {    
      const lastP = faucet[2]
      d.state = 1
      d.x = lastP[0]
      d.y = lastP[1]
      console.log("a1",[d.x,d.y])
   })  

  circle.filter(d => d.state == 1)
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => {
    console.log("a2",[d.x,d.y])
    return d.y
  })

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the transition is complete, you are both transforming with translate and positioning with cx/cy, which results in the position being off.

During the transition you set the transform for each circle:

```
 .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
```

Afterwards you position by:

```
   .attr("cx", d => d.x)
   .attr("cy", d => d.y)
```

But this is added to the end transition point/translation (the end of the faucet). This is why everything appears normal except off by a fixed amount.

Just reset the transform after the transition.

[Example](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/25240f5ae580b4f1514991d2d982826f)

Or alternatively, update the translate with the new x/y values rather than using cx/cy.

Comment: Great ! how can I rest the transition translation in the enter() phase, so it only gets called once and not every refresh ?

Comment: You could set the translate in the end function (updated [block](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/49610336b766fd4bdaed5ce562b479e1))